# Quickly Leaving Math Text to Continue Typing in Texmaker

Tags: texmaker

In Texmaker, I like using the shortcut to enter math mode.  This shortcut creates two dollar signs, and allows you to immediately type text in between the two.

My problem is that I would like to be able to continue typing outside of this block immediately upon finishing with my math text.  I would like to, say, hit "tab" and be able to start typing outside the math block, one space after the latter dollar sign.

How do I do this? Is there a shortcut for this?  If not, can I create one?

Alternatiely: Can I edit the Math shortcuts that come with Texmaker?  I don't mean that I want to edit the keys I press to obtain the code -- rather, I would like to change the code that is available from the Math menu.

Comment: Related Texmaker [Issue Tracker Thread and workaround](https://code.google.com/p/texmaker/issues/detail?id=1138&can=1&q=exit%20math%20mode&colspec=ID%20Type%20Summary)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Note: You may have multiple accounts on SE, please ask mod to join both of them, may be at meta.tex.sx

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on above Issue Tracker Thread, One may add a `User Tag` Shortcut as per [Texmaker User Tag demo video](http://youtu.be/UxCx78bgCTY).

for example for an exit from inline math mode, create a user tag as `inmathexit` as shown below with

```
 $@$ @
```

in LaTeX content. `@` is for place holder **•**. The first placeholder will be replaced with the math symbols while typing and with TAB key one can move from first place holder to second place holder to type the running text and exit math mode.

Also refer to **Using the "•" place holders** section of Texmaker doc 
http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/doc.html#SECTION113

[image]

For more information on handling **Personals tags and tools**:

http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/doc.html#SECTION33